# How to solve de differential equation $u'' + (1+x²)u=-1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the differential equation:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 u}{\mathrm{d} x^{2}} + (1+x^{2})u = -1$$ 
with $\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d} x}(0) = 0$ and $u(1) = 0$.

I tried Laplace and Fourier Transforms but they simple end up in new diff equations that are nonlinear and very similar to the original. 
Trying using Taylor series I could not find an answer too.

The best I could get was looking for a power series solution:

$u(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n}x^{n}$.

However I still can't get an exact formula for the solution.

Comment: This equation has no simple analytical solution in elementary functions (but it can probably be expressed as a some combination of [parabolic cylinder functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderFunction.html)).

Comment: I really wonder if there is any explicit solution to this equation. If you are only concerned by the $(0,1)$ range, I think that the easiest would be the power series solution $u(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n}x^{2n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This differential equation has a solution in terms of the [Parabolic cylinder functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderFunction.html). You may solve for $\nu$ first, upon a suitable change of variables.

Once you solve for the homogenous part, say $y_h = A y_1(x) + B y_2(x)$, you may find a particular solution trying solutions of the form $y = A(x) y_1(x)$ (or $y = B(x)y_2(x)$). I'm afraid that the resulting integrals are going to be a nightmare.

You can also find an approximation to $y(x)$ using WKB theory (have a look to Bender & Orszag).

Cheers!

PS: You may find useful some of the answers to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297457/how-do-i-solve-the-following-differential-equation/1297466#1297466) question.

Here's a numerical solution to your problem using Matlab:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Dmoreno. In Matlab I can solve it easily with some numerical method, MDF for example.  The problem resides in finding this analytical solution. Your answer helped me a lot. 

Best Regards!

Comment: You are very welcome @Victor. Happy to help.